# Proof with symmetric matrix (Direct and Contraposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

$S$ is a symmetric matrix. If $Sx=\lambda x$ and $Sy = \mu y$, where $x$ and $y$ are non-zero vectors and $\lambda , \mu \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove the following:

(a) If $\mu \neq \lambda$, then $x^{t}y=0$. Prove by contraposition.

(b) $(S^4 + S^2 + S)$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda^4+\lambda^2+\lambda$. Give a direct proof.

Help on this would be much appreciated - I'm very new to proofs!

Comment: I hope you tried the exercise yourself.  Using symmetry of $S$ makes the first part very straightforward.  Definitions are your friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Part a

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\lambda x^T y
&=& (x^T S^T) y \\
&=& (x^T S) y \\
&=& x^T (S y) \\
&=& x^T (\mu y) \\
\end{array}$$

Therefore $(\lambda-\mu)(x^T y) = 0$

### Part b

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
S x &=& \lambda x \\
S^2 x &=& \lambda^2 x \\
S^3 x &=& \lambda^3 x \\
S^4 x &=& \lambda^4 x \\
S^4 x + S^2 x + S x &=& \lambda^4 x + \lambda^2 x + \lambda x \\
(S^4 + S^2 + S) x &=& (\lambda^4 + \lambda^2 + \lambda) x \\
\end{array}$$